# matrix index matching for large raster data

Tags: r, matrix, indexing, raster, large-data

I have a large raster data (X) with a dimension of 32251*51333. The values of X are repetitions of another array (Y), which has a size of 3*10^6.
Now I want to change the values of X by matching it against each value of Y, for example I can program like this,

```
for (i in 1:length(Y)){
 X[X==Y[i]] = Z[i]   #Z is just another array with the same size as Y
}
```

The problem is that, first the index matching `X[X==Y[i]] = Z[i]` does not work because X is too large. After a few minutes the program just stops by giving an error `"Error: cannot allocate vector of size 6.2 Gb".`
Second, going over the loops from 1 to length(Y), even though Y is of size 10^6, may take "forever" to complete.

One approach came to my mind is to split X into small chunks and then do the index match for each chunk. But I feel this would still take a lot of time.

Is there a better way to achieve the above goal?

### 1st Update:

Thanks to the example provided by @Lyngbakr, I will elaborate this question further. Because the raster I'm working with is very large (32251*51333), it seems not possible to upload it. The example given by @Lyngbakr is very similar to what I want, except that the raster created is too small. Now following the example, I ran two tests by generating a much larger raster with dimension of 3000*2700. See code below.

```
#Method 1: Use subs
start_time <- Sys.time()
Y <- 1:9
Z <- 91:99
X <- raster(matrix(rep(Y, 3), nrow=3000,ncol = 2700))
df <- data.frame(Y, Z)
X <- subs(X, df)
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time
#Time difference of 2.248908 mins

#Method 2: Use for loop
start_time <- Sys.time()
Y <- 1:9
Z <- 91:99
X <- raster(matrix(rep(Y, 3), nrow=3000,ncol = 2700))
for (i in 1:length(Y)){
  X[X==Y[i]]=Z[i] #this indexing of R seems not efficient if X becomes large
}
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time
#Time difference of 10.22717 secs
```

As you can see, a simple **for** loop is even more efficient than the subs function. Remember, the raster shown in the example is still smaller than what I work with (about an order of 100 smaller). Also, the array Y in the example is very small. Now the question could be, how to speed up the Method 2, which is just a simple for loop?

Comment: We need a small example of each of these raster objects. First load any needed packages with `library` calls, then make small examples and state what is expected as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `subs` function. I don't know if it works with large rasters, but here's how you'd try.

I load the `raster` package and create some dummy data. (It would be *really* helpful if you provide data in your question.) Then, I plot the results.

```r
# Load library
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp

# Z holds values that will replace Y
Y <- 1:9
Z <- 91:99

# Create dummy raster
X <- raster(matrix(rep(Y, 3), ncol = 9))

# Examine raster
plot(X)
```

[image]

As you can see, `X` is just a bunch of `Y` vectors patched together. Next, I bind `Y` and `Z` together into a data frame `df`.

```r
# Combine y & z into a data frame
df <- data.frame(Y, Z)
```

Finally, I use `subs` to replace `Y` values with `Z` values.

```r
# Substitute Z for Y in X
X <- subs(X, df)
```

A quick look at the raster shows that the values have been replaced correctly.

```r
# Examine raster
plot(X)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

---

### Update

`Rcpp`is really helpful when performance is an issue. Below, I compare three methods:

1. Looping in R (from the question)
2. Using `subs` from the raster package
3. Looping in C++ using `Rcpp`

By the way, `Sys.time()` isn't a great way to examine performance, so I'd recommend `microbenchmark` instead.

```r
# Load library
library(raster)

# Define vectors and raster
Y <- 1:9
Z <- 91:99
X <- raster(matrix(rep(Y, 3), nrow = 3000, ncol = 2700))
```

`method_1` is the `subs` function.

```r
# Using subs function
method_1 <- function(){
  df <- data.frame(Y, Z)
  X <- subs(X, df)
}
```

`method_2` is your original looping approach.

```r
# Using R loop
method_2 <- function(){
  for (i in 1:length(Y)){
    X[X==Y[i]]=Z[i] 
  }
  X
}
```

`method_3` is the looping approach implemented in C++.

```r
# Using Rcpp loops
src <-
"Rcpp::NumericMatrix subs_cpp(Rcpp::NumericMatrix X, Rcpp::NumericVector Y, Rcpp::NumericVector Z){
  for(int i = 0; i < Y.length(); ++i){
    for(int j = 0; j < X.ncol(); ++j){
      for(int k = 0; k < X.nrow(); ++k){
        if(X(k, j) == Y(i)){
          X(k, j) = Z(i);
        }
      }
    }
  }  

  return X;
}"

Rcpp::cppFunction(src)

method_3 <- function(){
  subs_cpp(as.matrix(X), Y, Z)
}
```

And here I benchmark the approaches.

```r
# Run benchmarking
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(method_1(), method_2(), method_3(), times = 10)

# Unit: milliseconds
#       expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
# method_1() 16861.5447 17737.2124 19321.5674 18628.8573 20117.0159 25506.208    10
# method_2()   671.2223   677.6029  1111.3935   738.6216  1657.0542  2163.137    10
# method_3()   316.9810   319.1484   481.3548   320.2337   326.7133  1477.454    10
```

As you can see, the `Rcpp` approach is by far the fastest.

You can also compare the output to ensure they produce the same result using a smaller raster.

```r
# Examine all three outputs with smaller raster
X <- raster(matrix(rep(Y, 3), ncol = 9))

plot(method_1(), main = "Method 1")
plot(method_2(), main = "Method 2")
plot(raster(method_3()), main = "Method 3") # Needs to converted into a raster
```

And they all look alike. Note that for the third method, the result needs to be converted back to a raster from a matrix.

Comment: @uPhone Was the `Rcpp` solution fast enough?

Comment: Yes. It was faster. But I was hoping to get an answer with an elegant algorithm that is simple, such as vectorization. I feel this straightforward problem should have some shortcut solutions.